# Remove blank characters from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that needs to be cast into a date. In IE, my string has an unknown character in it, and it says invalid date when I cast it.

When I run

```
var dateString = $('#DueDate').val()
for(var i = 0; i < dateString.length; i++){console.log(dateString[i]);}
```

this is the output:

```
// empty line that I can't format in Stack overflow correctly
0
1

/

0
1

/

2
0
1
2
```

And `dateString.length` outputs `15`. These characters cannot be spaces because `dateString.valueOf()` outputs `"‎01‎/‎01‎/‎2012"`

Also, if I copy and paste where these special characters should be from the control itself into the IE console, the Developer tools window freezes.... If I backspace from the control in the right places, it works fine (presumably because the special characters aren't there anymore). How can I search for and remove this character?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @Crappy OP does not know what the character actually is, so specifically targeting it with `replace` may not be their best option.

Comment: Thanks to @Santi: it was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I search for and remove this character?

You could utilize a regular expression.

The following will remove anything that isn't a number or a `/`:

```js
var dateString = '12___/15___/20_17_xxx';         // Poorly-formatted date string
dateString = dateString.replace(/[^0-9/]/g, "");  // 12/15/2017

var date = new Date(dateString);                  // Cast as date
console.log(date);                                // 2017-12-15T05:00:00.000Z
```

---

If you'd like some more information about what the "weird" character may be, you can loop through the contents of the string and log each character code to the console:

```js
var str = "Hello!";
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  console.log(str.charAt(i) + ": " + str.charCodeAt(i));
}
```